# How to apply colour animation to button in Android Studio like what shown by material design?

Tags: android, animation, button

So, I want to make something like this: https://material-design.storage.googleapis.com/publish/material_v_4/material_ext_publish/0B3T7oTWa3HiFSTNhRndpWXBwRDA/components-buttons-flatbuttons.webm

The pressed state is what I want for this moment.
How can I get this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's called Ripple.

You could either implement it yourself (check out [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/RippleDrawable.html) link) or use a library (ex: [RippleEffect](https://github.com/traex/RippleEffect))